# What is the right way to simplify a tensor expression (with many indices, but no derivatives) in Mathematica?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, tensors, xact

After not finding the desired capabilities in base Mathematica, I am trying to use `` xAct`xTensor `` package. It appears that I do not need most of it capabilities though: I have an expression with tensors, where indices go over $1,\dots,d$, $1,\dots,J$, or $1,\dots,S$, where positive integers $d,J,S$ are unknown, and need to expand simplify that expression given known properties of the tensors involved. I didn't find a dedicated way to specify a vector space in `` xAct`xTensor ``, so I am assuming it is supposed to be a vBundle over 0-dimensional manifold. Thus, I am trying to define:

```
DefManifold[M0, 0, {}];
DefVBundle[vBd, M0, nd, {a, b, c, d, e, f, a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1}];
DefMetric[1, metricvBd[-a, -b], PrintAs -> "gd"];
```

Unfortunately, this fails with an error `DefMetric::noicovd: Metrics in inner vbundles do not support covariant derivatives`. Why is that? Is there a way to specify that I do not need any derivatives (and, in fact, would be more than happy with the trivial metric $\delta_{ab}$) and avoid that error or a better library to use for that purpose?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the above issue seems to be to explicitly specify `covd` (3rd) argument of the `DefMetric` function as `None`:

```
DefMetric[1, metricvBd[-a, -b], None, PrintAs -> "gd"];
```

I've found this by finding the code of `xTensor` package in `.Mathematica/Applications/xAct/xTensor/xTensor.m` and reading the condition where the message `DefMetric::noicovd` gets thrown:

```
DefMetricCheck[signdet_,metric_[-ind1_,-ind2_],covd_,covdsymbol_,flat_,inducedfrom_,confto_,odeps_,wwb_,eoib_]:=Module[
  ...
  If[tangentmetricQ,
    ...,
    (*else branch*)
    If[covd=!=None,
      Throw@Message[DefMetric::noicovd];
    ]
  ];
  ...
];
```